# Missing glyph character and garbage replace leading 5 characters of file name when written to disk

Tags: vim, fonts, freebsd, jail

```
FreeBSD-12.1p5
vim-8.2
```

I have a zfs clone of an iocage thick jail that I am using for testing.  When I open a file with `vim` in character mode and I use `:wq` to save my changes then I see these characters in place of those expected (`/usr/:`)

```
[>4;mlocal/etc/smb4.conf" 24L, 672C written
```

There is a missing glyph character (a single square box one character in width and height with hex decimal characters [0..F] inside) that is positioned immediately before the `[` character in the sample given above.  This character disappears when this message is displayed.

This does not happen if I use `:w` by itself, only when I use `:wq`. It appears that vim actually displays the correct string when I use `:wq` but that the first few characters are immediately overwritten.

This is not a problem with the file name or path, only with what vim displays when saving.

I have not encountered this before.  Why are these characters messed up when vim displays the name of the file it is saving?

I have verified all packages are intact and all dependencies installed.  I have also reinstalled vim.  The problem remains.

Comment: That's supposed to be an [escape sequence](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php). Not sure where the problem is though.

Comment: What do you have `$TERM` set to? Are you using vim in the FreeBSD console or a terminal emulator, if so which? Consider using a different setting for `$TERM` (such as `xterm` or `vt100`) or also use a different terminal emulator to see if you still have the same issue...

Comment: I have the same problem, that started a few weeks ago, but I thought it was caused by ssh'ing into a FreeeBSD box from a Linux box I'm testing with and it was a Linux issue. But questions about the Linux operating system and its utilities are off topic here and should, instead, be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ Please delete this and ask over there. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Vim is the software that I am having a problem with and it is not clear to me that the problem is specific to FreeBSD.  And vim is a software development tool, at least that is how I view it.  In my opinion this more likely has something to do with locales than with the OS but I do not know what.

Answer (score 0):

Should be resolved by adding these lines to your `.vimrc`:

```
set t_TI=
set t_TE=
```